# How to check which files cause a driver to be digitally unsigned?

Tags: windows-7, windows, windows-10, drivers, nvidia-geforce

I've got a nVidia driver that's digitally unsigned. How can I know which file is that exactly? I would like to digitally sign it to be able to install the driver without having to disable driver signature enforcement on Windows 7 or 10.

[image: nVidia driver 9.18.13.4192 digitally unsigned]

Comment: Where did you get the driver? The legitimate NVIDIA ones should be signed: http://i.imgur.com/Vtmt6ED.jpg

Comment: The official INF file is patched to work on old optimus laptop.

Comment: the 341.92 supports your GPU: http://www.nvidia.com/download/driverResults.aspx/94792/en-us So I have no idea why you edited the inf file. This (of cource) breaks the signing,

Comment: I'm using this INF patcher:

http://forum.notebookreview.com/threads/latest-vpc-z1-330m-drivers-for-the-bios-hack-people.602497/
The official signed driver won't install because it fails. I would like to know how to sign the patched one.

Comment: you can't sign a modified file. Extract the driver and update the driver via device manager if the setup shows an error.

Comment: It is unsigned because, it isn't signed by Nvidia, that is the entire point of a signed driver ( it cannot be modified without becoming unsigned thus indicating its been modified).  How do you tell if the light is off, its not on, that is the closest example to this question.

Answer (score 0):

> I'm using this INF patcher: forum.notebookreview.com/threads/...

That is the reason. Signing a driver is done by someone with the right certificate. The person signing it guarantees that the driver is fine.

This can only be done by trusted persons. (Otherwise every malware creator would sign his or her own malware).  Windows therefor only trusts a few entities to sign a driver.

And you, as private person who just hacked in a driver, are not one of those trusted people. So it is not signed by a recognised entity. And thus not implicitly trusted.

> I would like to know how to sign the patched one

Either add yourself to a list of trusted signers on windows (no idea how), or have someone who is trusted sign it. Smetherlinks links fro mthe other answer should help with that.

Answer (score -1):

I see. I would need a certificate from the WHQL program, approved by Microsoft to sign the INF file. That way, I could install the driver without disabling Driver Signature Enforcement. I could also create and install a custom certificate by me, and sign all the unsigned drivers then they will install directly on my computer. However, it's not a practical solution in order to install a simple driver once in a while. Lucky that it's possible to disable driver signature enforcement on windows 7 and 10, I hope Microsoft never removes that possibility.

[Windows Digital Driver Signing and Certification](http://www.jungo.com/st/support/documentation/windriver/11.0.0/wdusb_manual.mhtml/driver_sign.html)

[Practical Windows Code and Driver Signing](http://www.davidegrayson.com/signing/)

Comment: One of your links don't even work.

Comment: You provided `http://ractical%20Windows%20Code%20and%20Driver%20Signing` now you provided `http://www.davidegrayson.com/signing/` this has nothing to do with `%20` not being supported.  The two are vastly different.